# Ubuntu 10.04: Firefox doesn't accept keystrokes after unlocking screensaver

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, keyboard, gnome, screensaver

Ubuntu 10.04 With Gnome

Every time Ubuntu goes to the screensaver and I unlock it, Firefox won't let me type anything.  I can move the mouse and type in other programs... just not in Firefox.  If I quit Firefox and reopen it again, I can type in it.

My keyboard connection is PS/2.  Sounds buggish?

---

Update #1 - Hmm... this time around, I just waited for a minute and it appeared to return to normal.  I still think it's a bug but at least it's not as bad as I originally thought.

Comment: Coming from windows to ubuntu I have had so many problems with firefox and its addons.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm this strange behaviour. I use Minimize to tray extension, so I have to `pkill firefox` each time.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem (Ubuntu 10.04 x64), and it does not go away; as soon as my machine resumes from monitor sleep, Firefox does not accept keyboard input.

My workaround is to bring up the System->Preferences->Keyboard dialog, which must toggle some widgets and reinitialize the keyboard.  It works every time.

I've found that this behavior is accompanied by an error message that resembles this:

```
npviewer.bin[...]: segfault ... error X in libflashplayer.so[...]
```

I know that there are some problems with 64-bit browser/32-bit flash player (since the 64-bit flash player 10 has been pulled by Adobe), so I am not looking too far into the issue; we're lucky to have flash at all right now.

Edit: here is someone else complaining about the same issue: http://www.linux.com/learn/answers/4-distributions/425-losing-keyboard-input-on-firefox-on-wake-also-random-xserver-restarts